# Analytical Solution to Poisson's equation with sinusoidal source

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

In a domain $\Omega=[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$, consider the Poisson equation 
\begin{align}
-\Delta u=\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)
\end{align}
inside $\Omega$, and $u(x,y)=0$ for $(x,y)$ in the boundary of $\Omega$.

By inspection i know that 
\begin{align}
   u(x,y)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)}{-2\pi^2}
\end{align}
solves the Poisson equation boundary value problem.

I tried to obtain that solution convolving the source term of Poisson equation with the fundamental solution associated, in this part i was not able to compute a analytical expression for this convolution.